# OnNext not being called on observable when using combineLatest and take

Tags: rx-java2, rxandroidble, unsubscribe, combinelatest

I'm trying to get a subscription to automatically unsubscribe when it emits an item. The base observable is created like this.

```
public static Observable<RxBleConnection> setupConnection(RxBleDevice device, PublishSubject<Void> disconnectTrigger) {
    return device
            .establishConnection(false)
            .takeUntil(disconnectTrigger)
            .retry(3)
            .retryWhen(o -> o.delay(RETRY_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .compose(new ConnectionSharingAdapter());
}
```

Then I try to combine three read operations into a `ProgramModel`.

```
private void readCharacteristics(Action1<ProgramModel> onReadSuccess) {
    mConnectionObservable
            .flatMap(rxBleConnection ->
                    // combines the following three observables into a single observable that is
                    // emitted in onNext of the subscribe
                    Observable.combineLatest(
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID_SERIAL_NUMBER),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID_MACHINE_TYPE),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID_CHARACTERISTIC),
                            ProgramModel::new))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .take(1)
            .subscribe(programModel -> {
                programModel.trimSerial();
                onReadSuccess.call(programModel);
            }, BleUtil::logError);
}
```

So theoretically once a program model is comes through `oNext` of the subscribe, the subscription will be unsubscribed from. For some reason the operation gets stuck and `onNext` and `onError` are never called. If I remove the `take(1)` this works fine but I don't want to have to deal with holding onto a reference to the subscription and unsubscribing manually. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or why `onNext` is not being called?

Comment: What is `ConnectionSharingAdapter`. Do the individual `readCharacteristics` produce any items? Put `doOnNext` at various places to see where events disappear.

Comment: The connection sharing adapter is part of `RxAndroidBle`. Since every time subscribe is called a connection to the device is created, so the connection sharing adapter basically makes sure only one is active at a time. I'll try the `doOnNext`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call `take(1)` before the `flatMap` as well as after. This post sort of explains it [Read multiple characteristics from an Android device using library RxAndroidBle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670256/read-multiple-characteristics-from-an-android-device-using-library-rxandroidble)

Comment: From my knowledge of `RxJava` this should not be the case and the code from original post should work as expected—one of subscribe actions should get called. Could you add `RxBleLog.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.VERBOSE)` and more logging if the part where you create `Observable.combineLatest` is called? There must be some cause of the behaviour you are experiencing.